# Does the order of $a$ in $\left(\mathbb{Z}/ \Phi_n(a) \mathbb{Z} \right )^{\times}$ equal $n$?

Tags: number-theory

Here, $\Phi_n(a)$ is the nth cyclotomic polynomial evaluated at a.

It's obvious that the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $\Phi_n(a)$ divides $n$, because $a^n \equiv (a^n-1)+1 \equiv P(a)\cdot \Phi_n(a)+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{\Phi_n(a)}$ for some polynomial $P(x)$. But numerical data suggests that not only does the order of $a$ divide $n$, but actually the order of $a$ always equals $n$.

I have no idea how to approach this, and any hints or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, what is $a$?

Comment: @Dave Sorry for not specifying. $a$ is an integer greater than 2.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. What condition prevents me from choosing $a$ and $n$ freely?

Comment: @Dave What I'm trying to prove is that this is true for arbitrary $n>0$ and $a>1$.

Comment: The order of $2$ modulo $\Phi_6(2)=3$ equals $2$, not $6$. But I haven't found another counterexample. You'd need to look among $n$ with $n/\phi(n)\ge3$, just for size reasons.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand the notation $|a|$.

Comment: @GregMartin First of all, thank you for your edit.
Second of all, why $n/\phi(n)\geq 3$ exactly? If $n=2^k$, we have $n/\phi(n)=2$, but I tested with it and I see no problem thus far.
I see no constraint that would make $\phi(\Phi_n(a))$ always greater than $n$ right now, so maybe I should just edit the OP and add $|a|=\min(n,\phi(\Phi_n(a))$.

Comment: $\Phi_n(a)$ is roughly $a^{\phi(n)}$ in size. If the order of $a$ modulo $n$ is to be smaller than $n$, then the largest possibilities are $n/2$ and $n/3$. But $\Phi_n(x)$ divides $x^{n/2}+1$, not $x^{n/2}-1$, and so $a^{n/2}$ is congruent to $-1$ modulo $\Phi_n(a)$; therefore the order cannot be $n/2$. So the largest possible order is $n/3$. In particular, $a^{n/3}$ has to be greater than $\Phi_n(a) \approx a^{\phi(n)}$. That's why it's best to look at $n$ such that $n/\phi(n)\ge3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that apart from the cases (1) and (2)

(1) $n=6$, $a=2$, where $ord_{\Phi_6(2)}(2)=2$

(2) $n=2$, $a=2^s-1$, $s\ge2$, where $ord_{\Phi_2(2^s-1)}(2^s-1)=1$

it is true that $ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)=n$.

This is a corollary from Zsygmondi's theorem: when neither (1) nor (2) holds, there exists some prime $q$ so that $n=ord_q(a)$.

$q$ must be a divisor of $\Phi_n(a)$, because $q$ divides $a^n-1$, and no other $a^m-1$ where $m\lt n$.

Since $\Phi_n(a)$ divides $a^{ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)}-1$, then $q$ also divides $a^{ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)}-1$, then $ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)$ must be a multiple of $ord_q(a)$,

that is $ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)$ is multiple of $n$, but since you have shown that it is obvious that  $ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)$ divides $n$, then we have $ord_{\Phi_n(a)}(a)=n$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, I didn't know of Zsygmondi's theorem beforehand.